# SkyDrive is now OneDrive

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request, retag-request

[OneDrive for Everything in Your Life](http://blog.onedrive.com/onedrive-for-everything-your-life/)

> Today we are pleased to announce that SkyDrive will soon become OneDrive.

We only have a couple questions tagged [skydrive](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skydrive), but it would be nice if they were re-tagged as [onedrive](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/onedrive) and "skydrive" was made a synonym.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merged. Thanks for the request.